# How to change an image tag url in multiple html files using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

There are more than 10 html files with image tags. Every time we deploy our build onto test site we need to change the img source. for eg `<img src=/live/Content/xyz.png />`
to `<img src=/test/Content/xyz.png />`.
After looking around and reading for sometime, i have come up with the following batch script, however i cant figure out how do i go further from here :

```
for /r %%i in (*.html) do echo %%i    
for %%f in (*.html) do ( 
FOR /F %%L IN (%%f) DO (
  SET "line=%%L"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
  SET "x=     <--------------------WHAT DO I SET HERE?
  echo %x%
  ENDLOCAL  )) pause
```

This is my first batch script, could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You have a good answer but using a tool like SED is a robust option.  Or repl which is also a robust option: - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /r U:\ %%i in (*.html) do (
 echo found %%i    
 SET outfile="%%~dpni.lmth"
 (
  SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion
  FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%L IN ("%%i") DO (
   SET "line=%%L"
   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
   SET "line=!line:/live/=/test/!
   echo !line!
   ENDLOCAL  
  )
  ENDLOCAL  
 )>!outfile!
)
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

How about this development?

Notes:
I've modified your `FOR/R` to `ECHO` the HTML file being processed and use `%%i` rather than switching to `%%f`. `U:` is my RAMDRIVE; you'd need to modify that to suit.

`outfile` is set to generate a filename which matches the HTML filename, but with a `.lmth` extension (can't update in-place) - it gets that from the `~dpn` prefixing the `i`, which means the `d`rive, `p`ath and `n`ame of the file `%%i`. It's quoted to take care of potential spaces in the filename or pathname.

The next logical statement is `(for /f...[lines] )>!outfile!` which sends any `echo`ed text to a NEW file `!outfile!`. The `enabledelayedexpansion` in the second physical line of the batch makes `!outfile!` the RUN-TIME value - as it is changed within the `FOR r` outer loop.

Since the actual HTML filename in %%i may contain spaces, it needs to be quoted, hence the 'usebackq' clause in the `FOR/F`. The `delims=` clause ensures that the ENTIRE line from the file `"%%i"` is applied to `%%L` - not just the first token (well, actually, makes the entire line the first token).

The `SET` command substitutes the string "/test/" for any occurrence of "/live/" in the RUN-TIME value of the variable `line`and assigns the result to `line`. The resultant value is then `ECHO`d - which is redirected to `outfile`

Note that in your original, you would be assigning `x` in the `set x=` but `echo %x%` would have reproduced `x` as it stood when the line was PARSED because batch substitutes the value of any variable for %var% as part of the parsing phase. Consequently, the line would have become simply `ECHO` (since `x` would likely be unassigned) and bizarrely would have reported the `echo` state (`Echo is OFF`)

A couple of gatchas here. First, `%` and some other characters are notoriously hard to process with batch, so be careful. Next, `FOR/F` will bypass empty lines. This can be overcome if required. Third, this will replace  ANY occurrence of `/live/` in any case with `/test/`

Good luck!

---

Edit to support exclamation marks: 20130711T0624Z

Added `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` line and `ENDLOCAL` just before `)>!outfile!` to match

Comment: Appreciate your time and explanation :).

Comment: @Endoro True - fix inserted :)